# Accessing Amazon MWS inBound shipments

Tags: amazon-mws, inbound

I want to access MWS Inbound Shipments API form C# in a similar way I do with the Amazon Reports using MarketplaceWebService

But I don't know how to to it.
For example how can I do this call form c# : https://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/fba_inbound/FBAInbound_ListInboundShipmentItems.html?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and quickest approach is to download the C# SDK for MWS, where you can create a client and call the `ListInboundShipmentItems` method directly.  For this particular operation, `ShipmentId` is required.  All you need to do is add your AWS keys and token (if applicable) and make the call.   I noticed that the SDK used to be publicly available, but I think now you are required to log in with a seller account.

If you are not using the SDK, your request should look like this:

```
http://mws.amazonaws.com/FulfillmentInboundShipment/2010-10-01/
  ?Action=ListInboundShipmentItems
  &Version=2010-10-01
  &AWSAccessKeyId=1QZHP81EXAMPLEN5R44N
  &MWSAuthToken=amzn.mws.4ea38b7b-f563-7709-4bae-87aeaEXAMPLE
  &SignatureVersion=2
  &SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256
  &Signature=VY6sqvdk01VeEXAMPLEG0Vh4oj3
  &Timestamp=2015-12-01T02:40:36Z
  &SellerId=1234567890
  &ShipmentId=SSF85DGIZZ3OF1
```

Make sure you read the [developer guide](https://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/dev_guide/DG_IfNew.html) too.